# GSUTIL traceback-Linux Mint

Tags: gsutil

Im trying to install GSUTIL, after installation it gives the following output for every command,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gsutil", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 632, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist,req) # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (httplib2 0.8 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('httplib2>=0.9.1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

That means you need to update the version of httplib2 installed on your system to at least v 0.9.1.